Do functions within a component remain in memory even after execution ends?
I have a question about the code below Nextjs.
The handleContactClick function is expected to be deleted from memory when the UserDetail component function ends, so I thought it was necessary to use useCallback, but it runs normally.
Are functions within a component maintained in memory even after execution ends?
'use client';

import UserProfileCard from './user-profile-card';

export default function UserDetail() {
  const user = {
    profilePicture: 'profile/1.png',
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@eexample.com',
  };

  const handleContactClick = () => {
    window.alert('Contact button clicked!');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>user profile</h1>
      <UserProfileCard user={user} onContactClick={handleContactClick} />
    </>
  );
}


I can't speak to specific implementation of garbage collectors in each browser, however in theory no. The entire object should be destructed and resources reclaimed from all child entities. Do you have a specific memory problem with this code?

If by "component function ends", you mean, "component isn't rendered anymore", then yes, the handleContactClick function is not in the memory. UserDetail isn't just any "function" though, it's a react component.
Side note about react components is that they are... reactive and are rendered again and again (Not executed, but rendered!) everytime there's a change in their state. In your particular example, however, this does not really matter much. I only mention this in case you are thinking of components as regular functions and the same as all others.


The handleContactClick function is expected to be deleted from memory when the UserDetail component function ends

It will be garbage collected once nothing is referring to it any more. But you've passed it into a <UserProfileCard>, which has presumably passed it into the onClick of some dom element like a <button>, which has then made a subscription for the click event, which has saved a reference to your function so it knows what to call when the click happens.
In all likelyhood, this will continue to be the case until UserDetail renders again or unmounts. At that point, the event listener unsubscribes.  Assuming nothing else is still keeping a reference to the function, it can now get cleaned up.
